# displaying nested arrays using jade+mongoose

Tags: mongoose, pug

my schema looks like this

```
var user = new Schema({

    Achievement: 
    [ { name: String,
    description: String,
    xp: Number
    }],

},
    {collection:'user'});
```

but I get nothing when I refer to the document using jade

```
#{user.Achievement}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case Achievement is an Array and you want to display the first value

```
ul
  each item in user.Achievement
  li #{item.name} (#{item. description}) #{item.xp}
```

Comment: I get an error...Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. In my routes I implement req.user, which should reference all of the data represented in the schema

Comment: then you need two each loops - one for all users, and one for each achievement